# Is it possible to run java web application using eclim?

Tags: eclim

Is it possible to run java web application using eclim? How to do that?

I use maven so I can create war file by using `mvn install` command and copy/deploy war file to some web server like tomcat. I think this solution is not convenient. Is there a better way?